# Error: No tidy method for objects of class standardGeneric

Tags: r, class, error-handling, tidy

I am running a function 'map' from a package '[tipsae](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tipsae/index.html)'. And I am sure that I've set the right inputs for the function to run (using SPDF class as input for 'x' argument). Thus it become like this:

```
tipsae::map(x = my_summary_fitsae,
            spatial_df = my_SPDF,
            spatial_id_domains = "ID")
```

However, I get this error:

> **Error: No tidy method for objects of class standardGeneric**

Can anyone give me insight of how to solve it?

I have tried to look for the similiar error:

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class lmerMod

This (above) particular error can be solved by installing package "broom" and "broom.mixed". However, that solution does not work in my case because my error is regarding the **class standardGeneric**. Can anyone give me insight of how to solve it?

PS: the 'map' function can be seen in the page 15 of the [package manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tipsae/tipsae.pdf)

Comment: Can you provide the code that produced the error?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List all packages used. It's hard to guess what's going on with just the text of an error message.

Comment: Hi, @MelissaKey I just added some additional information, could you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @MrFlick .. I just added some additional information, could you take a look? Thanks!

Comment: I have no experience with the `tipsae` package, but even for someone who is, they will probably need you to include `my_summary_fitsae` and `my_SPDF` as part of your reproducible example (or smaller representative versions that give the same error - it's the form that is usually important, not the specific values.)